# Как получить доступ к удаленной базе MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server

У напарника на ПК стоит база данных `MS SQL`, `IP` статичесский. Можно ли мне как-то получить доступ и работать с ней через свою `SSMS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо сделать следующее.
Сначала настроить сервер

- Необходимо [Настроить сервер для прослушивания указанного
  TCP-порта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177440.aspx)(по умолчанию 1433). Также настроить файреволл для разрешения
  входящих подключений на заданный порт.
- Иметь или создать нового пользователя на SQL сервере, под именем которого будем подключаться

Теперь что касается клиента. При запуске `SSMS` появляется окно для подключения к базе данных. Заполняем ее

- В поле *ServerName* - (ip адрес сервера)(имя экземпляра
  SQL сервера на сервере). Если на удаленной машине установлен только один
  экземпляр SQL сервера, то имя экземпляра указывать необязательно, достаточно указать только ip.
- *Autentification* - выбираем SQL Server authentification
- Ну а в полях *User name* и *Password* вводим аутентификационные данные пользователя, созданного на сервере.

**P.S** После настройки сервера также можете запустить `telnet` и проверить доступность открытого порта на сервере. Откройте telnet и введите что-то такое

`192.168.0.1 1433`

Если порт прослушивается, можно пробовать подключаться через `SSMS`

Если будут возникать вопросы, спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то ты хочешь находясь на одном сервере делать запросы к другому серверу без переключения между серверами?

В таком случае почитай про Линкованные сервера.

Вкратце: Указываешь IP удаленного сервера в настройках линкованных серверов в MS SQL Server и можешь находясь на одном севере писать запросы такого вида к другому серверу :

```
Select * from [Название удаленного сервера].[схема].[Таблица]
```

Правда, есть некоторые ограничения... Например, нельзя выполнять запросы к таблицам, где есть XML...

Comment: Хотелось бы работать с удаленной базой, как будто бы она у меня на ПК стоит.  Делать запросы, удалять/создавать таблицы, редактировать данные и т.д..

Comment: В таком случае мой ответ немного мимо... А его IP пингуется у тебя? Что если при запуске SSMS указать его IP и учетку?

Comment: В файрволле и сервере эскьюл нужно разрешить входящие подключения

Comment: @iluxa1810, `IP` пингуется, но IP и учетка для ssms не канают. Я уверен что есть какие-то настройки в SSMS чтобы открыть доступ для внешних пользователей, только проблема их найти.